# Is it possible to design a setup step to be triggered when installing a Microsoft Teams App?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm designing the architecture for a Microsoft Teams app.

This app is an integration to a multitenancy platform that the customer can set up their own URL to access the system, i.e: https://app.customer.com/

I was wondering if there is a standard way to have a step on the app installation to set up the instance URL.

I understand I could design an app generator that would reside inside each customer instance and then deliver the manifest.zip to the customer to install it, but I feel we would lose all marketing and partnership opportunities that having it on the store would provide.

Comment: I've added a suggestion also to Microsoft Teams UserVoice: 
https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/38972791-have-a-setup-step-on-app-installation-to-ask-for-e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a standard way so I designed a proposed solution and wanted to validate it with the community.

I came with a list of issues and workarounds to work with a single app for the multiple instances based on what we've seen so far on Microsoft Teams documentation.

**Issue 1**: Accessible domains should be explicitly set on the manifest.json

> **Workaround**: have a middleware in a fixed URL that handles all requests made by the app and route to the customer site

**Issue 2**: There is no standard step on an app installation to set up the instance URL

> **Workaround**: Design a static tab that would handle the configuration, so in that tab, the admin would need to set up any
>   configuration like instance URL

**Issue 3**: After installation, the feature will be available for the users even before admin did the setup to define the customer instance URL to be used.

> **Workaround**: Make all designed interactions (i.e.: Tabs configuration page, bot response, actions, cards, etc... ) have a
>   response to the user saying there are pending configurations in case
>   the admin did not set the URL yet

Comment: Would the static tab for issue 2 save a tenant-ID-to-instance-URL mapping in a DB on your middleware server?

Comment: @GabrielDeal yes this is part of the designed database.